# Not catching specific errors with Try and Except

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alright, so I've got a try and except block watching out for exceptions.
This is all normal but when you've got a loop you can't stop the code usually, as there's no specific bit saying "Don't catch KeyboardInterrupt errors" or something alike

Is there anything that let's try and except blocks exclude specific errors? (or an alternative)

My code

```
     while 1:
        if ques == 'n':
            try:
                newweight = int(input('Please enter a number'))
                exit()
            except:
                print('Please enter a valid number')
```

Now this will create an infinite loop as the "exit()" will not happen as it will get raised an as exception, and it will thus create an infinite loop. Is there any way for this to not happen?

Comment: You can specify the precise type of error you *do* want to catch: presumably ValueError. Or at most catch Exception, since an exit is not a subtype of Exception. Bare `except` is bad for exactly this reason.

Comment: In my opinion, you should use exceptions only for exceptional cases. I don't know the full purpose of your code, but invalid user-input is pretty normal and most programs account for it. You could try using if statements instead.
(I know this doesn't answer your question regarding try-except blocks, but I thought it could be helpful at the very least).

Comment: @DanteCulaciati Python is well know for using exceptions in flow control. eg. StopIteration, GeneratorExit, and others.

Comment: What's the point of entering a number if you are going to exit the script immediately?

Comment: @Dunes Thanks for letting me know! I don't have lots of experience with the language itself. I was talking from a more general point of view.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent a user entering a non-integer value, you want to catch a TypeError so you can change `except:` to `except ValueError:` and it will then catch any invalid inputs. That should cover you sufficiently.

Comment: `ValueError`, not `TypeError`. `input` always returns a `str`, which is always a valid type for the argument to `int`.